# Ambiguous access to base class template member function

Tags: c++, templates

In Visual Studio 2008, the compiler cannot resolve the call to `SetCustomer` in `_tmain` below and make it unambiguous:

```
template <typename TConsumer>
struct Producer
{
    void SetConsumer(TConsumer* consumer) { consumer_ = consumer; }

    TConsumer* consumer_;
};

struct AppleConsumer
{
};

struct MeatConsumer
{
};

struct ShillyShallyProducer : public Producer<AppleConsumer>,
                              public Producer<MeatConsumer>
{
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ShillyShallyProducer producer;
    AppleConsumer consumer;
    producer.SetConsumer(&consumer);   //  <--- Ambiguous call!!

    return 0;
}
```

This is the compilation error:

```
// error C2385: ambiguous access of 'SetConsumer'
//    could be the 'SetConsumer' in base 'Producer<AppleConsumer>'
//    or could be the 'SetConsumer' in base 'Producer<MeatConsumer>'
```

I thought the template argument lookup mechanism would be smart enough to deduce the correct base `Producer`. Why isn't it?

I could get around this by changing `Producer` to

```
template <typename TConsumer>
struct Producer
{
    template <typename TConsumer2>
    void SetConsumer(TConsumer2* consumer) { consumer_ = consumer; }

    TConsumer* consumer_;
};
```

and call `SetConsumer` as

```
    producer.SetConsumer<AppleConsumer>(&consumer);   // Unambiguous call!!
```

but it would be nicer if I didn't have to...

Comment: I'd just like to point out that in your proposed workaround, you don't need to call `SetConsumer<AppleConsumer>(&consumer)`, `SetConsumer(&consumer)` will suffice (and deduce the template argument correctly).

Comment: @sbk: No, it will not. I tried that before posting, and now once again  to be sure. Still ambiguous.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I thought the template argument lookup mechanism would be smart enough to deduce the correct base Producer.

This hasn't to do with templates, it comes from using multiple base classes - the name lookup is already ambiguous and overload resolution only takes place after that.

A simplified example would be the following:

```
struct A { void f()    {} };
struct B { void f(int) {} };
struct C : A, B {};

C c;
c.f(1); // ambiguous
```

Workarounds are explicitly qualifying the call or to introduce the functions into the derived classes scope:

```
 struct ShillyShallyProducer : public Producer<AppleConsumer>,
                               public Producer<MeatConsumer>
 {
     using Producer<AppleConsumer>::SetConsumer;
     using Producer<MeatConsumer >::SetConsumer;
 };
```

Comment: @gf: "introduce the functions into the derived classes scope" - That's a great solution, as I don't want to change the producer clients' call sites every time I add a new produced product. Lovely - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can just use explicit qualification in your function call. Instead of:

```
producer.SetConsumer(&consumer);
```

try:

```
producer.Producer<AppleConsumer>::SetConsumer(&consumer);
```