# Resolving overloading ambiguity with multiple inheritance of base class templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overloading, template-meta-programming

Let's say I'm trying to create a `Combine` class that will be derived from the given base classes.

```
template<typename ...Bases>
class Combine : public Bases... {};
```

And this works fine. For example, if I have class `Foo` and class `Bar` then class `Combine<Foo, Bar>` will implement all the methods from `Foo` and `Bar`. At least I thought so until I tried this:

```
struct ContainerProvider {
    std::vector<int> container{1, 2, 3};
};

struct ConstGetter : public virtual ContainerProvider {
    [[nodiscard]] const int &get(int index) const {
        return container[index];
    }
};

struct MutableGetter : public virtual ContainerProvider {
    int &get(int index) {
        return container[index];
    }
};

template<typename ...Bases>
class Combine : public Bases... {};

int main() {
    Combine<ConstGetter, MutableGetter> container;
    container.get(1); // Member 'get' found in multiple base classes of different types
}
```

In normal situations, I would just use `using Super::method;`, but here I don't know the names of derived methods. In a perfect world, I could use something like this:

```
template<typename ...Bases>
class Combine : public Bases... {
    using Bases::* ...;
};
```

But C++ does not allow this.

Is it possible to implement my `Combine` class somehow? I'm pretty sure the compiler can get all the information to resolve this edge case, but I have no idea how to provide it to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that renaming `ConstGetter::get()` to `ConstGetter::const_get` is not an option? However, this compiles: `container.ConstGetter::get(); container.MutableGetter::get();`, check it [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hn4v8eoGP)

---

As of why overload resolution doesn't work across classes, you could check
this old [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/79784efb-78c2-474e-8752-00ae418c78c2/multiple-inheritance-and-function-overloading?forum=vclanguage)
and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2713282/7143595) of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713160/ambiguous-access-to-base-class-template-member-function).

Comment: Yes, this will work, but I want to make `Combine<...>` as general as possible, so it would work with any classes given. And specifying parents in method calls will only make the interface more complex. I think I will either stick with this option for now or rethink the entire interface of a library I'm trying to write.

Comment: @eL'teammate You have surely greater goals that I can't grasp from your small snippet: using templated multiple inheritance to differentiate const/non const getters seems quite warped to me :-) My small advice about interface design is: give the users the possibility to make their intent clear when they call your facilities

Answer (score 0):

Curious problem since get() defined only in one class would work perfectly, but in two? Error? I was curious if there might be a core language defect since this problem seems solvable by the compiler, but I didn't see any (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html).

The ideal solution would probably be for `MutableGetter` to inherit from `ConstGetter` since, logically, a getter that allows mutation should also allow grabbing non-mutable versions.

```
struct MutableGetter : public ConstGetter {
  using ConstGetter::get;

  int &get(int index) {
    return container[index];
  }
};
```

Here's the closest I could get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct ContainerProvider {
  std::vector<int> container{1, 2, 3};
};

struct ConstGetter : public virtual ContainerProvider {
  [[nodiscard]] const int &get(int index) const {
    std::cout << "CONST" << std::endl;
    return container[index];
  }
};

struct MutableGetter : public virtual ContainerProvider {
  int &get(int index) {
    std::cout << "NON-CONST" << std::endl;
    return container[index];
  }
};

template <typename... Bases>
class Combine;

template <typename B1, typename B2, typename... Bases>
struct Combine<B1, B2, Bases...> : public B1, public Combine<B2, Bases...> {
  using B1::get;
  using Combine<B2, Bases...>::get;
};

template<typename B>
struct Combine<B> : B {
  using B::get;
};

int main() {
  Combine<ConstGetter, MutableGetter> container;
  std::cout << container.get(0) << std::endl;  // non-const
  const auto &const_container = container;
  std::cout << const_container.get(0) << std::endl;  // const
}
```

It really sucks for the `Combine` to have to know what member functions its parents expose, though. I found one partial solution if you're willing to drop the idea of member functions and occasionally do a cast...: Use friend functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct ContainerProvider {
  std::vector<int> container{1, 2, 3};
};

class ConstGetter : public virtual ContainerProvider {
  [[nodiscard]] const int &get(int index) const {
    std::cout << "CONST" << std::endl;
    return container[index];
  }

  friend [[nodiscard]] const int& get(const ConstGetter &self, int i) { return self.get(i);  }
};

class MutableGetter : public virtual ContainerProvider {
  int &get(int index) {
    std::cout << "NON-CONST" << std::endl;
    return container[index];
  }

  friend [[nodiscard]] const int &get(MutableGetter &self, int i) {
    return self.get(i);
  }
};

template <typename... Bases>
class Combine : public Bases... {};

int main() {
  Combine<ConstGetter, MutableGetter> container;
  std::cout << get((MutableGetter&)container, 0) << std::endl;
  const auto &const_container = container;
  std::cout << get(const_container, 0) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If a class inherits two methods that have almost the same signature from two parents, you have to give the compiler a clue to disambiguate the call

Comment: @MatG That much is clear, but do you know why this instance cannot be disambiguated while similar examples (such as if the two functions are in the same class) can be? If so, maybe you could post that as an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: As of why overload resolution doesn't work across classes, you could check
this old [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/79784efb-78c2-474e-8752-00ae418c78c2/multiple-inheritance-and-function-overloading?forum=vclanguage)
and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2713282/7143595) of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713160/ambiguous-access-to-base-class-template-member-function).